# mdb with node js hosted on Heroku does not work

Tags: node.js, ms-access, heroku

I used 'node-adodb' nodejs module with .mdb database. Here is my code.

```
const ADODB = require('node-adodb');
const connection = ADODB.open(`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=${__dirname}/data/Database.mdb;`);

module.exports = { connection : connection };
```

This is worked on a local and throws the following error after hosted on Heroku.

```
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421683+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421683+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421684+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421684+00:00 app[web.1]: at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421685+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421686+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-adodb/lib/engine.js:16:24)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421686+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421687+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421687+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421687+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421688+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421688+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421688+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-adodb/index.js:11:16) {
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421689+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
2020-04-23T21:53:16.421689+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```